# How to add value in array in java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm new in java, what is the right way to add/pass a value into array string without specifying the array index.

I want to add a value into array like what in php array do.

```
static String[] var_productname = new String[20];

public void setProductName(String productName){
    var_productname[] = productName;

}
```

Comment: 1) I'm not sure Android is the good starting point for "new to Java". 2) `static` doesn't play well with setter methods 3) Why is a "productName" an array? Sounds like a singular object

Comment: Are you asking how to expand the array capacity, or how to keep an implicit index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Based on your example:

```
static List<String> var_productname = new ArrayList<>();

public void setProductName(String productName){
    var_productname.add(productName);

}
```

The initial capacity is optional, but you can instantiate the array using `new ArrayList<>(20)`, where 20 is the initial (not maximum) capacity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to avoid specifying the index when calling `setProductName`, here is a simple approach. (However, the method will internally use and update the index).

*Note that this simple implementation will throw an exception if you attempt to append more than 20 strings. Also, I made `setProductName` a `static` method, which makes more sense since you made `var_productname` `static`.*

```
static String[] var_productname = new String[20];
static int pnIndex = 0;

public static void setProductName(String productName) {
    var_productname[pnIndex++] = productName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array can't  append element direct,change array to other data structure

Comment: answers should be longer than one line;change answer to describe a more complete solution in context and maybe use full sentences and punctuation

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would go for a concept called [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/)

The problem with Arrays is that you cannot dynamically increase it's size at run time and you will only be able to add values as per the length specified.

As `int[] nArray= new int[20];` will hold only 20 items you cannot further dynamically increase the size from `20` to `21` and add the element.

As suggested above you can go for any [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) implementation.